# Aplicação de contraste na página por meio de cookies

Tags: javascript, html, lógica, cookies, acessibilidade

Tenho um botão em uma barra de acessibilidade, que quando clicado chama a seguinte função:

```js
function contraste2 ()
 {
  var css = document.querySelector('#css');
  var contraste = Cookies.get("contraste");
  if (contraste == "contrasteinativo" || contraste =="undefined")
  {
   Cookies.set("contraste","contrasteativo", { expires: 365 });
   css.setAttribute('href', 'estiloscontraste.css');
  }

  if (contraste == "contrasteativo")
  {
   css.setAttribute('href', 'estilos.css');
   Cookies.set("contraste","contrasteinativo", { expires: 365 });
  } 

 }
```

A aplicação do css de contraste se dá por meio de um css alternativo, chamado na função.

Só que esse código tá errado, eu sei.

Se o contraste ainda não foi aplicado (cookie = undefined), então ele ativa o contraste e define o cookie como ativo.

Só que logo em seguida, ele verifica se o cookie está ativo, e se tiver ele desativa o contraste. Dessa forma, acaba que não há alteração nenhuma na página (pois o cookie sempre estará com valor de inativo).

Não estou conseguindo criar uma lógica pra isso, pensei em fazer uma espécie de contadora pra verificar se o botão já foi clicado, uma contadora por meio de um outro cookie.

Comment: De onde vem essa api "Cookies.set" "Cookies.get"

Comment: Estou incluindo dessa forma <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script> Segui as orientações daqui: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque o segundo if para apenas ser executado quando a primeira condição não é atingida.

No seu código o segundo if era sempre avaliado nesta versão apenas é avaliado se a primeira condição for atingida.

O *undefined* não é uma string portanto não deve estar entre aspas.

```
 function contraste2 ()
    {
        var css = document.querySelector('#css');
        var contraste = Cookies.get("contraste");
        if (contraste == "contrasteinativo" || contraste == undefined)
        {
            Cookies.set("contraste","contrasteativo", { expires: 365 });
            css.setAttribute('href', 'estiloscontraste.css');
        } else if (contraste == "contrasteativo")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', 'estilos.css');
            Cookies.set("contraste","contrasteinativo", { expires: 365 });
        }   

    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Já que não tenho ciência de onde vem o objeto `Cookies`, irei criar um exemplo usando a API nativa `sessionStorage`:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#change-contrast');
const link = document.querySelector('#css');

function getContrastState (toggleValue) {
  const state = sessionStorage.getItem('contrast-state');

  if (! state) sessionStorage.setItem('contrast-state', '0');
  if (toggleValue) sessionStorage.setItem('contrast-state', state === '1' ? '0' : '1');

  return sessionStorage.getItem('contrast-state') === '1';
}

function toggleContrast (toggleValue = true) {
  const contrastState = getContrastState(toggleValue);

  if (contrastState) return link.setAttribute('href', 'contraste-ativo');
  link.setAttribute('href', 'contraste-inativo');
}

// Inicializa:
toggleContrast(false);

// Reinicializa ao clicar no botão:
button.addEventListener('click', toggleContrast);
```

```html
<button id="change-contrast">Alterar Contraste</button>
<a id="css" href="#">...</a>
```

> Você terá que testar o código em outra página, já que o StackOverflow não permite que os trechos de código acessem o conteúdo de `localStorage` ou `sessionStorage`.
>
> Criei um [CodePen](https://codepen.io/lffg/pen/djaoaa) para demonstrar.

#### Referência:

- [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).